# Kibana Multiple Representations of single field

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

When I'm looking at my index in Kibana there are many representation in the index for the same field. Below is an example:

[image]

[image]

What I'm wondering about is, can I configure a way to hide the values that end users in Kibana don't need to see. I don't see anything in the "edit" section for each field that enables me to do so.

I'm trying to make kibana as user friendly as possible for end users and having 2 different representations is going to be confusing.

Is it something I need to configure in the Mapping? Sorry I'm just getting used to the new Kibana interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out a field by adding it to the source filters on the Index Pattern. Management > Index Patterns > Source Filters